# collection view cell dynamic height issue

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

i want to implement collectionView that support dynamic heights for cell depend on autoLayout.  i have product cell which contain image and at bottom of it stackview which contain its price and discount price and timerLabel where product offer will finish . some times the product has no offer so i need to hide timer from stackView then cell height will change .
i used this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
homeCollection.delegate = self
homeCollection.dataSource = self
homeCollection.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
(homeCollection.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize

}
```

then for test in cellForItemAtIndex i used this code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
    if indexPath.row  == 0
      {
        cell.productTimerLabel.isHidden = true

      }
return cell
```

}
the output was like that
[image]
my problem why the topAligment of first cell is more down than top aligment of second cell , i want both of them have same aligment

Comment: try replacing "cell.productTimerLabel.isHidden = true" with "cell.productTimerLabel.alpha = 0"

Comment: bro i want hide it to change cell height , my problem just why it dont start at top of collectionview like the second cell

Comment: The first row has two cells with different height, so the height of the row is the height of the tallest cell. And every cell is centered in that available height.

Comment: is there any way to make it not centered and start from top ??
or other way to implement to acheive what i want

Comment: You need to use a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, or use detect maxheight for each "line" and do a top alignement with an "invisible cell part" at the bottom. It creates the illusion you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` for that because `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is always centred and not top aligned as you want.

I would suggest you use [Aligned collection view flow layout](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout) that I used from `Github`. It has a property that allows you to top align with `verticalAlignment = .top`